# Joining multiple paired RDDs in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join 3 files and output the final file in console using pyspark. I've converted them to pair RDDs and I'm able to join 2 of them without any problem. But for some reason I'm not able to join 3rd paired RDD to the previously joined RDD. Below is the structure of 3 files.

EmployeeManager.csv

```
E01,John
E02,Kate
E03,Emily
```

EmployeeName.csv

```
E01,Brick
E02,Blunt
E03,Leo
```

EmployeeSalary.csv

```
E01,50000
E02,50000
E03,45000
```

Below is the pyspark code that I've so far.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())

manager = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeManager.csv')
name = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeName.csv')
salary = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeSalary.csv')

managerPairRDD = manager.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
namePairRDD = name.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
salaryPairRDD = salary.map(lambda x: x.split(','))

ns = namePairRDD.join(salaryPairRDD)
print 'After name and salary join: \n %s' %ns.collect()

nsm = managerPairRDD.join(ns)
print 'After joining 3 files: %s' %nsm.collect()
```

The program stops running during the last step. Below is the console output

```
[cloudera@quickstart Spark]$ pyspark q7.py
WARNING: Running python applications through 'pyspark' is deprecated as of Spark 1.0.
Use ./bin/spark-submit <python file>
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
After name and salary join:                                                     
[(u'E02', (u'Blunt', u'50000')), (u'E03', (u'Leo', u'45000')), (u'E01', (u'Brick', u'50000'))]
[Stage 3:=======================================>                   (2 + 0) / 3]
```

Please let me know how to proceed to solve this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you give more information about Spark version? I'm running this on Spark 2.1.0 and it is working for me.

Comment: I'm running on Spark 1.6.0 on my Cloudera VM.

Comment: you can check the details about the stage in which the job is failing using the spark ui to debug more

Comment: The job is not failing. Instead it just hangs as if it was waiting for some resources. I couldn't find any thing helpful from spark ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured this out by converting the input files as dataframes.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

manager = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeManager.csv')
name = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeName.csv')
salary = sc.textFile('spark1/EmployeeSalary.csv')

manager_df = manager.map(lambda x: list(x.split(','))).toDF(["col1","col2"])
name_df = name.map(lambda x: list(x.split(','))).toDF(["col1","col2"])
salary_df = salary.map(lambda x: list(x.split(','))).toDF(["col1","col2"])

nsm = name_df.alias('name_df') \
.join(salary_df.alias('salary_df'), name_df.col1==salary_df.col1) \
.join(manager_df.alias('manager_df'), name_df.col1==manager_df.col1) \
.select(name_df.col1, name_df.col2, salary_df.col2, manager_df.col2)

nsm.saveAsTextFile('/spark1/q7sol')
```